# Trigger react select onchange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange, onselect

What is the best way to trigger onchange even on a select field in react?

Unfortunately, I have to use plain javascript to format and set a value programmatically but that doesn't fire React events.

What's the best way to fire those events?

Say I want to set a value of my select manually by `document.querySelector(selector).value = value;` how can I trigger the onchange event?

Edit: clarifying the question

Answer (score 0):

Its same as in normal JS and HTML

```
<select 
        value={this.state.selectValue} 
        onChange={this.handleChange} 
      >
```

So, handleChange is the function inside that react component itself. You can update component's state inside handleChange function.
Make sure you use value={this.state.selectValue} too. This way you are binding state to the select component.

Comment: I think I should have worded this differently.
Let's say I tried to set the value of my select this way `document.querySelector(selector).value = value;` how can I trigger the onchange event?

Comment: This is not the right way of doing things in react. I will recommend the way I mentioned above. 
Any strong reason why you want to do this?