# Is there any alternative for select which i can use to i want to trigger on change function thats why i want select

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image]

I want a select dropdown like this i want the options to have some bigger width and select should only show the symbol and as well change the baackground color on hover i re search and  get to know that we cant give style to option ‍♀️ its very sad to know but luckily i got this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select here they showed what i wanted at least most of except the selected symbol show only anyway what i am getting also cool

```
.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
```

They are targeting a class selected select i look on the html but i cant find it but the color is changing perfectly they reason i cant copy it exactly i am using react styled component i need to understand and write a easy solution for this that link tutorial is so difficult anyone can explain or suggest me alternative of select

Note I am using react style component

```
export const NavbarSelect = styled.select`
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;

    option{
        background: #FFF;
        width:114px;
        height:45px;
    }
`
```

i want to style the option here

Comment: Have you created this select component yourself or is it a package? Either way, more context is needed, I'm sure if it is a package they have a way to do it but it is hard to say without knowing which library it is.

Comment: i created the style component  myself, you can provide the html css solution i will convert it to what i need

Comment: Do you know punctuation exists? Pls use full stops and commas in appropriate places because it is very hard to read now. Also there are some typos.

Comment: sorry i have fixed it now

Comment: You are using a native select element, but that won't work. you need to fully create one yourself or use a library like https://react-select.com/

Comment: Native browser elements do not support that level of customization

Comment: @Marlom I am writing a test i am not allowed to use any external libraries

Comment: @Marlom can you suggest me a way by which i can trigger the onchange without using the select

Comment: Don't mean to be rude but you should learn how to search by yourself. Just after you ask here, that is how you improve as a software engineer.
https://www.google.com/search?q=create+a+select+with+react&oq=create+a+select+with+react - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69924118/trigger-react-select-onchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't style all parts of the standard HTML select list box.

Is it crucial to have the classic HTML select element underlying?

If not, you could easily create your own ul. In react, you have to show the custom ul on click on the actual selected option (e. g. an input-like field). When clicked on an option, just set this option for your component and pass it to your form component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different element, like a UL. But please take care about resulting accessibility constraints. The select element have native interaction behavior (with keyboard and mouse for exemple) AND a specific meaning in the AOM (Accessibility Object Model) that allow assistive technologies to expose the element to the end user with the expected user experience. You have to reproduce the interactions AND correctly expose the ARIA roles/attributes. Stricts patterns have to be followed : https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/

In your case, for reproduce a "fake" select element, you have to follow the combobox pattern : https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/

Looking for an implementation ? You can use something like that : https://whatsock.com/Templates/Comboboxes/index.htm Or search "JS ARIA combobox widget"

There is many implementations for react.

If your site is to rent a car, and you think that you don't have to take care about accessibility, considere this scenario : An assistive technology user wants to help his son to choose a car for rent regarding about price and selectable technical informations. So, we have to never presume about the user accessibility context.